# Extended list comprehension options - Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I will use an example of code from a Project Euler exercise.

```
[(a, b, c) for a in range(1, 334) for b in range(1, 334) for c in range(1,334) if c == 1000 - a - b and a < b  and b < c and a**2 + b**2 == c**2]
```

I know very little about list comprehensions but was wondering if there was a way to imply that a, b, c are ints > 0 and you want to increment them

Two pseudo code examples for this might be something like:

```
[(a, b, c) for a > 0 for b > a for c > b if c == 1000 - a - b]
[(a, b, c) for int(a) for int(b) for int(c) if c == 1000 - a - b]
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplification to your approach:

```
[(a, b, 1000 - a - b) for a in range(1, 332) for b in range(a+1, 333)  if  a**2 + b**2 == (1000 - a - b)**2]
```

- `c` is fix, its always `1000 - a - b` so no need to make a loop of
  values for it.
- You can start the range of `b` as `range(a+1,333)` so you dont have to 
  test if `b>a`

Though its wrong as a solution to problem I think

Comment: Yeah, I was derping with different ranges and seeing the impact on time to completion (I know triple nested for loops are an AWFUL approach). Thanks for the input! It's definitely a step in the direction I was looking for

Comment: upper limit of `b` should be more than 333

Comment: yeayeah, I have the solution already, i did it initially with range (0,997) but then tried to find ways to skip range entirely, and then wondered what changing the values would do to the computation time

Comment: I did upvote, keeping it open a bit longer to see if there are other solutions. I almost closed on Jshura's answer but then yours came in.